# How to update apollo-client's cache after mutation?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

After a mutation I am updating the cache with "writeQuery". Now once I refresh the page, the changes done by mutation are gone and page restores to previous state (before mutation). On second refresh I get the consistent view.

**From apollo-client [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#writequery-and-writefragment)**: "If you reload your environment then changes made with writeQuery and writeFragment will disappear."

Approaches already tried:
1. Changing fetchpolicy to cache-and-network: This works but displays old view for a second and then reloads to correct view. Also an additional cost of network fetch
2. Using "refetchQuery" in mutation instead of "writeQuery": Without refreshing the page, no changes appear on page.

What I want is after the mutation, the changes immediately appear on the page and persist after refreshing the page. Can someone please suggest an alternative approach as I am struggling to find a solution from quite a while. Thank you

Comment: I just wanted to thank you so much. I'm having the same issue and tore my hair out not knowing why my query writes weren't persisted. It can be quite frustrating sometimes. Did you find a solution or how did you go about this? I'll look into this now.